# Does python-requests support HTTP2 and asynchronous calls?

Tags: asynchronous, python-requests, http2

I would like to use python-requests in my server to send PUSH notification to Apple push server, my questions:

1. Does python-requests support asynchronous calls?
2. Does python-request support HTTP2?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 10):

As [recommended by @qris in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931070/does-python-requests-support-http2-and-asynchronous-calls#comment107866375_44931193), you should consider using **HTTPX** (https://github.com/encode/httpx/) .

It's in beta, but a 1.0 release [is planned](https://github.com/encode/httpx/issues/947).

It supports both async as well as HTTP/2 and provides a requests-compatible API.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't support HTTP/2 now (Release v2.18.1).
As in the doc (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

> Requests allows you to send organic, grass-fed HTTP/1.1 requests, without the need for manual labor.

But you can try `Hyper` if you need to send HTTP/2 requests:
https://hyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

> hyper supports Python 3.4 and Python 2.7.9, and can speak HTTP/2 and HTTP/1.1.

Comment: Given that Hyper is alpha software and hasn't had a release in 4 years, you may be better off with [HTTPX](https://www.python-httpx.org/). It's in beta, and planning a stable release very soon (April 2020).

Comment: hyper is [no longer maintained](https://github.com/python-hyper/hyper#hyper-http2-client-for-python)

Comment: requests doesn't [_and will not_](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5757#issuecomment-782695134) support HTTP/2