# python-requests how to send cipher name/http2

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, http2

I am trying to replicate the following client requests via python-requests.

[image]
Under client connection I see HTTP Version which is 2.0 and TLS version which is 1.3, as up to my knowledge I know that requests utilizes TLS 1.3. My requests are failing as of now.

And I wonder if I need to pass certificates. I would like to understand how this request is different from regular request which would be simply as

```
r = requests.get('someurl')
```

How can I use requests to  use the exact client connection show in requests? I don't fully understand each pointer, How would I use h2 ALPN/ with that specific cipher name? I am not expecting an solid answer to the question rather an explanation would be much more helpful!

Comment: update your question with the error message that you get from using requests

Answer (score 8):

[**`python-requests`**](https://github.com/psf/requests) doesn't support **HTTP 2** request. You can use [**`httpx`**](https://github.com/encode/httpx) package.

> HTTPX is a fully featured HTTP client for Python 3, which provides sync and async APIs, and support for both ***HTTP/1.1*** and ***HTTP/2***.

***Example***

```
import ssl
import httpx

# create an ssl context
ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(protocol=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
# ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS - Selects the highest protocol version that both the client and server support.
# Despite the name, this option can select both "SSL" and "TLS" protocols.

# set protocol to use
ssl_context.set_alpn_protocols(["h2"])

CIPHERS = 'ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+CHACHA20:DH+AESGCM:DH+CHACHA20:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+HIGH:DH+HIGH:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MD5:!3DES'

# set ciphers
ssl_context.set_ciphers(CIPHERS)

# httpx verify param lets you pass a standard library ssl.SSLContext
response  = httpx.get('https://example.com', verify=ssl_context)

print(response.http_version)
# outputs HTTP/2
```

> Instead of using `ssl.SSLContext`, you can also use [**`httpx.create_ssl_context()`**](https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/) to set the ssl context.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know [python-requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) is a library which currently<sup>1</sup> **doesn't support `HTTP/2.0`**. This [question has been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931070/does-python-requests-support-http2-and-asynchronous-calls#comment107866375_44931193).

However there are python libraries like [Python httpx](https://github.com/encode/httpx/) supporting `HTTP/2.0`!

Kind regards,

---

<sup>1</sup> Feb 16, 2021