# Does urllib3 support HTTP/2 Requests? Will it?

Tags: python, http2, urllib3, openapi-generator

I know the following about various python HTTP libraries:

- [Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) does [not support HTTP/2 requests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44931070/1473320).
- [Hyper](https://github.com/python-hyper/hyper) does support HTTP/2 requests, but is archived as of [early 2021](https://github.com/python-hyper/hyper/commit/b77e758f472f00b098481e3aa8651b0808524d84) and wouldn't be a good choice for new projects.
- [HTTPX](https://www.python-httpx.org/) does support HTTP/2, but this support is [optional, requires installing extra dependencies, and comes with some caveats about rough edges](https://www.python-httpx.org/http2/).
- [AIOHTTP](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/index.html) does [not support HTTP2 yet](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/changes.html?highlight=http2#id532) (as of mid April 2022).

  - The focus of this project is also not solely on being a client -- this package also includes a server.

The other major HTTP request library I'm aware of is [urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). This is what [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/) uses by default when generating python client libraries.

My Questions are:

**Can urrlib3 be configured to make HTTP/2 requests?**

I cannot find any information on http2 support in [the documentation](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/index.html#), and through my testing of a generated OpenAPI client, all requests are HTTP/1.1. If the answer is no currently, **are the maintainers planning HTTP/2 support**? I cannot find any evidence of this in the project's [open issues](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues?q=is%3Aissue+%22http%2F2%22).

Comment: HTTP/2 requires a complete rewrite.  The external interface can be the same, but the implementation is totally different.  I doubt you'll see any of the existing libraries add HTTP/2 support -- you'll see new libraries written from scratch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I asked about this in the urllib3 discord, and got an answer from [one of the maintainers](https://github.com/pquentin) that corroborates what [Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883316/tim-roberts) commented;

- Proper HTTP/2 implementations require async/await to take advantage of the main different feature in HTTP/2, which is [making requests in parallel](https://web.dev/performance-http2/).
- urllib3 in particular is not planning to support this because it'll in general require a rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to the listed HTTP/2 clients: [pycurl](https://pypi.org/project/pycurl/) can perform HTTP/2 requests very efficiently if [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/) is compiled with HTTP/2 support (same apply to HTTP/3).
The drawback is it's more complex to install.