# Python external gRPC request using wrong protocal

Tags: python, python-requests, grpc, grpc-python

I am writing an API for a website that involves making a request to their API. The link looks like this - `https://search.api.company.com/company.content.search.v1.Search/Search.`
The data looks very weird when viewed in dev tools shows a very odd payload being sent- [The payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkY1y.png), as well as a very odd payload being received. My current python code is this

```py
import requests
r = requests.post("https://search.api.company.com/company.content.search.v1.Search/Search")
print(r.text)
```

And my error is this -
`gRPC requires HTTP/2`

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The api is using Http / 2. This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931070/does-python-requests-support-http2-and-asynchronous-calls

Comment: The question has the grpc and grpc-python tags, and the URL has the same format as a gRPC endpoint, and the error message you get refers to gRPC. Have you tried using gRPC to access this API?